# Let $k$ be a division ring, then the ring of upper triangular matrixes over $k$ is hereditary

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, modules, ideals, projective-module

I'm reading *Ring Theory* by *Louis H. Rowen*, and he claimed that *The ring of upper triangular matrices over a division ring is hereditary* (it's on page 196, Example 2.8.13 of the book).

I think it should be pretty much straight-forward, despite the fact that I'm not clear how it must be true.

---

Here's my thought on the problem:

I know that a left (resp, right) *hereditary ring* is a ring such that all of its left (resp, right) ideals are projective.

Now, let $k$ be a division ring, and the upper triangular matrice ring over $k$, $U_n(k) = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc} k & k & k & \cdots & k \\
0 & k & k & \cdots & k \\
0 & 0 & k & \cdots & k \\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & k  \end{array} \right)$, and I'll now try to find the form of its left ideals (i.e, how they look like). Let $I_n(k) = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc} I_{11} & I_{12} & I_{13} & \cdots & I_{1n} \\
0 & I_{22} & I_{23} & \cdots & I_{2n} \\
0 & 0 & I_{33} & \cdots & I_{3n} \\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & I_{nn}  \end{array} \right)$ be any $U_n(k)$'s ideal. Since $k$ is a division ring, its ideal are $0$, and itself. Using the fact that $U_n(k) I_n(k) \subset I_n(k)$, I manage to arrive at the following facts:

1. Each $I_{ij}$ must be an ideal of $k$, hence either $0$, or $k$.
2. Consider the column $j$ if $I_n(k)$, $\left(\begin{array}{c} I_{1j}\\
   I_{2j}\\
   I_{3j} \\
   \vdots \\
   I_{jj} \\
   0 \\
   \vdots \\
   0  \end{array} \right)$, using the fact that $U_n(k) I_n(k) \subset I_n(k)$, we must have the descending chain $I_{1j} \supset I_{2j} \supset \dots \supset I_{jj}$

So, basically, the following form is one possible left ideal of $U_n(k)$: $\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc} k & k & k & 0 & k & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & k & k & 0 & k & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & k & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
0 &0 &0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0  \end{array} \right)$

Now, I don't think the above should be a $U_n(k)-$projective module at all, since I don't think it is a direct factor of any free $U_n(k)-$ modules.

Where have I gone wrong? :(

Thank you so much guys,

And have a good day,

Comment: It seems that you assume that the coordinates of the ideal are independent of each other. This is not always the case - for example in $U_2(k)$ take the left ideal $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & a\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$ .

Comment: When thinking about this, I think you are right. So it'll make this problem much harder than I think it should be, since you cannot explicitly express the form of your ideal in $U_n(k)$. There are some sort of relations between the elements in each column, and also relations between the elements in each row. Gosh. @@ How should I tackle it now? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $1\leq i \leq n$, the set $C_i = U_n(k)e_{i,i}$ is a left ideal, which is projective, since $\bigoplus C_i \cong U_n(k)$. Suppose $J$ is any ideal in $U_n(k)$ - let us show that we can write it as $J'\oplus C_i$ for some $i$, hence from the previous argument+induction it will be projective.

Let $i$ be the maximal index such that $e_{i,i}J\neq 0$ and choose some $0\neq v \in e_{i,i}J$. Note that by multiplying $J$ from the right by a matrix $A=I+\alpha e_{i,j}$ for $j>i$ we get an isomorphic left ideal and the index $i$ is still maximal such that $e_{i,i}JA\neq 0$. You can use such multiplications to transform $v$ into $\beta e_{i,j}$ for some $j\geq i$, and wlog assume that $\beta=1$.

The subideal $U_n(k)v$ is now just $Je_{j,j}\cong C_i$, and it is also easy to see that $J'=J(I-e_{j,j})$ is also a subideal so that $J\cong J'\oplus C_i$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Please let me have some time to think about your work.

Comment: Hi, I think there's one place that I'm not sure if I get it correctly. It's the first line in the last paragraph, I know that $U_n(k)v \cong U_n(k)e_{i, j}$, for some $j > i$. Now, let's denote $J$ as our new $J$ (i.e, the old $J$ after a finite number of right multiplications with matrices of the form $I + \alpha e_{i, j})$, I also know that $e_{i, j}$ is in our new $J$. But, how come $U_n(k)v \cong J e_{\color{red}{j, j}} \cong C_{\color{red}{j}}$? I'm very sorry, but for somehow, I don't get both equivalent signs. :( And btw, is it $C_{j}$ or $C_{i}$ as you wrote? Thank you very much, :*

Comment: Wait a min, I think misread your proof. Please let me read it again. Argh, ok, on reading it again, it makes perfect sense. Thank you very much, Prometheus, for your great help :* :*